# When I install pod1 it prevents me from installing pod2, when I install pod2 it prevents me from installing pod1

Tags: firebase, terminal, cocoapods, twilio, podfile

when I install pod 'Firebase' it prevents me from installing pod 'TwilioConversationsClient', when I [install pod 'TwilioConversationsClient'](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks#ios-sdk) it prevents me from installing pod 'Firebase'. I receive "[!] Unable to find a specification for `Firebase`" message in terminal.

```
    podfile
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'

target 'podname' do

pod 'TwilioConversationsClient'

  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  # Pods for podname

pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'


end
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

They install separately, but not together. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. I believe the problem is that you have removed the main CocoaPods spec URL when you added the Twilio spec URL. Add the following line above where your current `source` line is located (you need both):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'
```

This should help resolve the `Firebase` pod.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. Make sure to mark this answer as accepted so others who have this issue will know. Feel free to reach out if you have any more issues.